# How to add bold formatting, and/or cell color to inserted data only in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

Code Below:

'Compares columns between sheets and inserts any missing data in a new row
' data includes acct name and number along with standard biling and concatenation

```
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet

Set Sht1 = Sheets("Execute Billing")
Set Sht2 = Sheets("Account Master File")

For Cnt = 2 To Sht1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sht2.Range("A" & Cnt).Value <> Sht1.Range("B" & Cnt) Then
       Sht2.Rows(Cnt).Insert
       Sht2.Range("A" & Cnt).Value = Sht1.Range("B" & Cnt).Value
       Selection.NumberFormat = "000000000000000"
       Sht2.Range("B" & Cnt).Value = Sht1.Range("A" & Cnt).Value
       Sht2.Range("C" & Cnt).Value = Sht1.Range("C" & Cnt).Value
       Sht2.Range("D" & Cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1]*5+18)"
       Sht2.Range("E" & Cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[4]&TEXT(RC[-4],""000000000000000"")&RC[5]"
       Sht2.Range("F" & Cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]*100)"
       Sht2.Range("H" & Cnt).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]&TEXT(RC[-2],""0000000000000"")"
       Sht2.Range("I" & Cnt).Value = "'001"
       Sht2.Range("J" & Cnt).Value = "'0125"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Range object:

```
Sht2.Range("A" & Cnt).Font.Bold = True
Sht2.Range("A" & Cnt).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```